# Undefined index und error

Tags: views

I'm getting undefined index:und error. below is my code

```
$photoItem = file_create_url($node->field_thumb_img[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']);
```

Answer (score 0):

why not

> file_create_url($node->field_thumb_img[$node->language][0]['uri']);

Answer (score 0):

you can do $photoitem = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_thumb_img') ;

field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $langcode = NULL);

see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7